# Yahoo stock API retrieve trending stocks (market mover)

Tags: javascript, yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I am currently using the Yahoo finance API to retrieve stock data in my js application. I would like to implement a feature that shows the top market movers or trending stocks. 
Does anybody know how to structure the YQL query to retrieve a list of stocks that are marked as 'trending' or 'top movers'? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

sir!

I'm currently studying the variables in the yahoo.finance.quotes datatable, and I stumbled upon this one: TickerTrend, where ticker is probably the symbol.

The query

select  * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol="^GSPC"

made on the YQL Console, returns the value NULL, but for AAPL it returns this: &nbsp;======&nbsp; (which I don't know what it is).

hope this help you!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah I saw the `TickerTrend` key, however it's not really that useful (atleast for me) unless you can search for all stocks within a specific `exchange` meeting a specific condition (e.g `... LIKE '&nbsp;++%'`). It doesn't let you execute a query that omits the `symbol` key which is quite annoying!

Comment: Yep, it's not a very effective search. One way you can do this is download everything, and then generating your own trend... Don't know if it's plausible for you, but it's something!

Answer (score 0):

** Intelligent Stock Market API **
can easily be used to get trending stocks not only on yahoo but also on social media, you can find the [Python Sdk for this API here](https://pypi.org/project/Intelligent-Stock-Market-API/)

Hope you its all that you wish it to be